# ¿Por qué me da este error al instalar este programa, relacionado con MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Al instalar un programa, me aparece el siguiente error. ¿A qué puede ser debido? ¿Hay alguna manera de corregirlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Te indica que el socket no esta conectado, será que no lo tienes configurado. ¿Estas usando Unix, puede que no hayas tocado el fichero en `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`? Bastante poca información y un mensaje que creo que es intuitivo pero no sin mas información.

Comment: Estoy bastante pez en el asunto. Sigo investigando. Gracias por tus aportes y ayuda